# neo4jrb DeprecatedSchemaDefinitionError

Tags: neo4j, neo4jrb

I've a problem with Neo4jrb 8.1.1, Rails 5.1.1, Neo4j 3.2.0 CE

I have a City model with an Int id, the DB is read only with data imported from csv files.
What should I declare to get rid of the error?

So far, I thought that declaring

```
id_property :id
property :name
```

would be fine but it doesn't work.

Overall, I'm annoyed with these new migrations files because the Neo4J DB is already done, I'm not supposed to write or modify indexes or constraints.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error message you're seeing? I imagine you can solve the issue by creating an initializer and manually adding the relevant constraint(s) to the `ModelSchema`. Something like `Neo4j::ModelSchema.add_defined_constraint(City, :id)`. It's also possible that this could be done inside the Model itself. Some experimentation should solve the problem.

See the source code for more info:

- https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/8.1.x/lib/neo4j/model_schema.rb
- http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/neo4j/Neo4j/ModelSchema